# How to change default text to "No results" in UISearchDisplayController

Tags: iphone, xcode, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UISearchBar` and a `UISearchBarDisplayController` set up by a xib.
After a search with no result it says "No result" some lines down in the table.
How to modify default text?

Comment: 7 questions and you've marked none as accepted? Have any of your previous questions been answered sufficiently?

Comment: 2 of my 7 questions gave me help. I wrote feedback and marked answer as accepted. I have no idea why it says 0%

Comment: I thought it was enough to mark in the feedback as accepted, but I now know how to mark the sign in the left margin to make it green.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@interface ClassName : UIViewController {
    UILabel                     *noResultLabel;
    UISearchDisplayController   *searchController;
}

@implementation ClassName

- (id) init {
    // bla bla bla bla
    // some more bla
    // setup your UISearchDisplayController and stuffz
    noResultLabel = nil;
}

- (void) changeNoResultsText:(NSString *)text {
    if (noResultLabel == nil) {
        for (id subview in searchController.searchResultsTableView.subviews) {
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                if ([((UILabel *)subview).text isEqualToString:@"No Results"]) {
                    if (noResultLabel == nil) noResultLabel = subview;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (noResultLabel != nil) noResultLabel.text = text;
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)bar { 
    [self changeNoResultsText:@"Searching..."];
}

- (BOOL) searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self changeNoResultsText:@"Searching full search..."];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will probably only work if the locale is English.

Comment: Yes this will only work for English, you'll need to change "No Results" to handle other languages.

Answer (score 8):

You can also try this.

1. In your search display controller's table view delegate/data source, suppress -numberOfRowsInSection: to minimum of 1.
2. Then in your -cellForRowAtIndex: method, if your data source count is zero, change the label of the table view cell to something like "Searching..."